# Can we run the Selenium Webdriver test case in the background?

Tags: selenium, background, webdriver

I'm quite new to Selenium. I'm writing selenium code in Java and trying to run the test in IE browser. Whenever I tried to run selenium test case its taking mouse and keyboard control. Can we run the test case in the background??

Thanks in advance!!